# CAGradientLayer locations negative values

Tags: swift

The documentation on **CAGradientLayer locations** property specifies that  it must be set to an array of NSNumber from 0 to 1, but it actually works with negative numbers and numbers larger than 1.
Is it safe to use it this way?

It works the way you would expect

```
gradientLayer.locations = [0, 1]
```

[image: gradient 1]

```
gradientLayer.locations = [-0.3, 1.3]
```

[image: gradient 2]

Comment: What it seems to be doing is it starts from gradient from above the view by invisibly rescaling the measurement from 0 -> 1 to -0.3 -> 1.3. So for the gradient it has a view which is bigger than the view you are adding it to by 60% (30% on the top, 30% on the bottom). Also, it looks safe to use. Might even be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is safe to use negative or values >1. But if you use the layer might overlap on the other views. 
To overcome this issue we need to use masktobounds property to the parent layer.